# Using Redis to serve data to unsafe docker container

Tags: docker, redis

I am making a webapp with docker, i need to run code made by public user (not safe at all), i use redis to push some data between my containers (using a socket shared in a named volume)

[image: schema]

How can i forbid unsafe containers to send data to Redis?

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    command: >
      sh -c "chown redis /tmp/redis/
             redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"
    volumes:
      - redis_socket:/tmp/redis
  unsafe_container:
      build:
        context: ./docker
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      command: python unsafe.py
      volumes:
        - redis_socket:/tmp/redis:ro
      links:
        - redis
      depends_on:
        - redis
  data_in:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-data
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 /code/manage.py wait_db
             python3 /code/manage.py start_dc"
    volumes:
      - redis_socket:/tmp/redis
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
  volumes:
    redis_socket:
```

If i make a redis slave, can i set this one to only accept read from every connections except for the master redis?

Thanks

EDIT: After some tests, a slave is read only by default, but i can't connect the slave to the master using a socket, i dont find anything about this feature / issue on the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis replicas are primarily designed to allow high availability, and as such, connect over the network. They do not support UDS connections to the master.

You can, however, use socat to expose a Unix socket as TCP (for example https://serverfault.com/questions/517906/how-to-expose-a-unix-domain-socket-directly-over-tcp).